# Node js restart server in interval every day

Tags: node.js, linux

I have a node js script that is running on my server(Ubuntu 14.04). I want it to be automatically restarted every day repeatedly. Is it possible? Should I use bash, or can I do it from within the node js script? How to actually do it?

Comment: You should probably look into using a [task scheduler](http://askubuntu.com/questions/650387/how-do-i-create-a-task-scheduler-in-ubuntu) for Ubuntu.

Comment: I actually haven't a GUI access to that server. I have remote terminal only.

Comment: You should've read that post closer, you'd see it has a CLI.

Comment: ok sorry, next problem is I want to kill the server first and then start.

Comment: You're changing the question dramatically with that scenario. Sounds like you need a boot script and not a scheduled task. `ssh root@<remoteServer> /sbin/shutdown -r now` will restart the server. Then you'll just need to run a script at startup, [see this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: no I just want to call `killall node && nodejs /home/ftpuser/server/server.js` but it doesn't work in `crontab -e`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118665/discussion-between-duri-and-peteb).

Comment: I use forever to keep my node.js script running and I just coded the script itself to do `process.exit()` at 4am each day and then forever will start it up again.  When the script starts up, it calculates how many ms until the next 4am and sets a timer for that time.

Comment: Good comment!!! I will do it like that

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) jobs for your node.js apps.

This is an example: A job runs every day at 11:30 am

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 30 11 * * *',
  onTick: function() {
    /*
     * Runs every day at 11:30:00 AM.
     */
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
job.start();
```

You can find more document here: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: I would prefer some bash solution

Comment: @duri you asked if there was a way to do it using bash or node, if you didn't want a node approach you shouldn't have offered it as an acceptable solution in the question.

Comment: I was wondering if I can restart the node process from within it. not if there's a onTick function which runs every day... I can do the setInterval function to do exactly the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (more complicated) is to make bash file killing node process, than running again node server from shell.

```
$ ps aux | grep node
you   PID  1.5  0.2  44172  8260 pts/2    S    15:25   0:00 node app.js
$ kill -2 $!
#!/usr/bin/bash
node 'YOUR_NODE_SERVER.JS file path'
```

To automize execution of bash file use cron or Crontab if you are using Mac.
Add this line to cron file.

```
00 01 * * * /Users/admin/myShellFile.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to keep the process running and then in your script add a `setTimeout` and `process.exit` to force it to exit after the specified interval.

```javascript
setTimeout((function() {
    return process.exit();
}), 10000);
```